# Dynamically display meta data on a wiki page .aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a wiki page library where I would like to create a template that dynamically displays metadata related to that page. for instance:

created by
created on
modified by
modified on
category

Is there a way to dynamically bring in metadata to the page.aspx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code to display the metadata of the current page.

*Note: change the internal field names in the scripts to yours.*

```
<div id="displayDiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var pageName = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
var libraryName = "wikis";
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+libraryName+"')/items?$select=Author/Title,Editor/Title,OData__Category,Wiki_x0020_Page_x0020_Categories&$expand=Author/ID,Editor/ID&$filter=FileLeafRef eq '"+pageName+"'";
var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };
$.ajax({
    url : requestUri,
    contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
    headers : requestHeaders,
    success : onSuccess,
    error : onError
});

function onSuccess(data, request){
    if(data.d.results.length>0){
        var page=data.d.results[0];
        var author = page.Author.Title;
        var editor = page.Editor.Title;
        //single text
        var category = page.OData__Category;

        //Get Multiple Taxonomy Field value
        var categories="";
        var tags = page.Wiki_x0020_Page_x0020_Categories.results;
        if(tags.length>0){
            for(var i = 0; i < tags.length ; i++) {
                var tagLabel = tags[i].Label
                categories+=tagLabel+";";
            }           
        }       

        var content = "<b>Create By: </b>"+author+";</p><b>Modified By: </b>"+editor+";</p><b>Category: </b>"+category+"</p><b>Categories: </b>" +categories;
        $("#displayDiv").html(content);
    }
}

function onError(error) {
$("#displayDiv").html(error.statusText);
}
</script>
```

If you want to make it as the template, so that you don't need to enter code in each page manually, you need to use a page layout content type such as Enterprise Wiki content type in the library and create and design a custom page layout. Create new page based on the custom page layout.

[How to create a page layout](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-create-a-page-layout-in-sharepoint)

[How to display page metadata in the page layout](https://discoverlars.wordpress.com/2011/01/05/page-layout-to-show-modified-by-metadata-and-version/)